# Decomposing $x^4-5x^2+6$ over some fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

My book asks me to decompose

$$x^4-5x^2+6$$

over:

$K = \mathbb{Q},\\ K = \mathbb{Q[\sqrt{2}]},\\ K = \mathbb{R}$

For $K = \mathbb{Q}$, I substituted $x² = a$ to get:

$$a²-5a+6 = (a-3)(a-2)$$

So Getting back to $a = x²$ we get:

$$x^4-5x^2+6 = (x²-3)(x²-2)$$

Also, for $\mathbb{R}$ we can simply factor $x²-3 = (x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})$ and $(x²-2) = (x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$ so we have:
$$x^4-5x^2+6 = (x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$$

but what about 
$$K = \mathbb{Q[\sqrt{2}]}\ ?$$

Comment: Look at what you got for $\bf Q$, and see what more you can do with $\sqrt2$ available.

Comment: @GerryMyerson would it be $(x^2-3)(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$? But wouldn't $(x²-3)(x²-2)$ also be correct?

Comment: @GOC the second is not a complete decomposition over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$

Comment: $(x^2-3)(x^2-2)$ is also correct over the reals. But I took "decompose" to mean "decompose into irreducibles."

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that factorization is valid over any field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But aren't $x^2-3$ and $x^2-2$ reducible over the reals? How can $(x^2-3)(x^2-2)$ be correct?

Comment: @Théo, I'm replying to OP, who asked whether $(x^2-3)(x^2-2)$ would be correct over ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$. It depends on what one means by "decompose". OP's question made me question what OP means by that word.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, I see. That makes sense. OP, "reduce" might be the better word here, since (as I just learned), polynomial decomposition can mean [something else entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_decomposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work is correct; for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, you surely have
$$
x^4-5x^2+6=(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})(x^2-3)
$$
Is $x^2-3$ reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$? This would mean…